# Get instance attributes dynamically Swift 3

Tags: swift, key-value-coding

I'm trying to figure out a way to set/get the attributes of an instance of a class dynamically.

User class:

```
class User: NSObject {
    var email: String = ""
    var password: String = ""
}
```

I'm trying to set/get attributes something like this, (I know that `.send()` does not exists but I'm trying to find something like that if it's possible)

```
var user = User()
// Set
user.send('email') = "user_name@domain.com"
// Get
print(user.send('email'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html):

```
user.setValue("user_name@domain.com", forKey:"email")
print(user.value(forKey:"email"))
```

Comment: Any hope of using this capability on non-NSObject based types?

Comment: @PauloMattos No, this requires the objc runtime. However, see https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0161-key-paths.md You will almost certainly never be able to pass strings to non-Cocoa Swift this way (by design; that's horribly unsafe; at least until we have reflection, but even then it will be very different). But we will be able to indirectly reference properties. Today you would generally solve these problems using closures.

Comment: @PauloMattos On Apple platforms, for classes that don't inherit from `NSObject`, you can *technically* go through the Obj-C runtime yourself to do this (provided the property you want to change is exposed to Obj-C), so you *could* do something [like this](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/5f6c5ecd3badfaa69a7c9dbcbecb0f4f). This is possible because Swift classes are implemented as Obj-C classes under the hood. But yeah, besides for fun/curiosity, really don't do this. As Rob says, closures are usually the way to go (you'll note we could have done the same with `let setter = { c.str = $0 }`).

Comment: @Hamish I totally agree with you and Rob: String-based APIs are a bad design choice generally — I was asking out of hackish curiosity! BTW, thanks for that gist sample code. In particular, that inlined *function metatype declaration* of yours is really something :-)